# Do all class types in Swift implicitly implement AnyObject?

Tags: swift, anyobject

There is nothing in the Swift documentation that specifically mentions this other than AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. Do all class types in Swift implicitly implement AnyObject protocol?

```
class C {}  // Is this implicitly class C: AnyObject {}?
let c = C()

let anyC: AnyObject = c  // ok
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted pls point out the issues so I can fix the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyobject):

> ## AnyObject
>
> The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.